# How to add an object into ArrayList in java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Here are two classes, query sentence and stackov. An arraylist is used to store objects of query sentence class.But the recently added object is overriding the previous one.How do I add objects so that they are not overridden?

**QuerySentence.java**

```
public class QuerySentence {

    public static String query;
    public static String label;
    public QuerySentence(){

    }
    public QuerySentence(String query,String label){
        this.query = query;
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

**Stackov.java**

```
package QueryClassifier;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class stackov {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        QuerySentence qs1 = new QuerySentence("What state produces the best lobster to eat","LOCATION");
        QuerySentence qs2 = new QuerySentence("What is Dick Clark's birthday","DATE");
        ArrayList<Object> doclist = new ArrayList<Object>();

            doclist.add(0,qs1);
            doclist.add(1,qs2);

            int size = doclist.size();
               while(size>0)
               {
                    QuerySentence qs3 = (QuerySentence) doclist.get(size-1);
                    System.out.println("\nin loop : " + qs3.label + qs3.query);
                    size--;
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: try to indent your code correctly. Also there is no need to post two entire classes, just post the `ArrayList` manipulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem **doesn't come from your loop** but from your class `QuerySentence`. You're creating static objects, which means that you don't create different fields for different instances of your classes, but the class will have only a unique copy of them.
So what was happening here, you were assigning these value to your class `QuerySentence` :

```
QuerySentence qs1 = new QuerySentence("What state produces the best lobster to eat","LOCATION");
```

And then erased it whit this one :

```
QuerySentence qs2 = new QuerySentence("What is Dick Clark's birthday","DATE");
```

As you add two objects into your `ArrayList`, of course in your loop you will print two results. But only the results in qs2. Remove `static` from your fields declarations and it will work fine :

```
public String query;
public String label;
```

You don't need to index your query sentences while adding.

```
doclist.add(qs1);
doclist.add(qs2);
```

And you can also improve your loop. You could just do :

```
ArrayList<QuerySentence> doclist = new ArrayList<QuerySentence>();

// some code...

for(QuerySentence q : doclist)
{
    System.out.println("In loop : " + q.label + q.query);
}
```

Please also remember Java conventions : your classes should begin with an uppercase (`Stackov`). If you also work on encapsulation, it's better to declare your fields `private` and create `getters` and `setters` for them. With this your `for-statement` should look like this :

```
for(QuerySentence q : doclist)
{
    System.out.println("In loop : " + q.getLabel() + q.getQuery());
}
```

Comment: The for loop showing an error   "for(QuerySentence q : doclist)" as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to QuerySentence"

Comment: That's because you've declared your ArrayList as `ArrayList<Object> doclist = new ArrayList<Object>();`. Use `ArrayList<QuerySentence> doclist = new ArrayList<QuerySentence>();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
doclist.add(qs1);
doclist.add(qs2);
```

Answer (score 0):

index is not required add like this

```
doclist.add(qs1);
doclist.add(qs2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       public static void main(String args[])
        {
            QuerySentence qs1 = new QuerySentence("What state produces the best lobster to eat","LOCATION");
            QuerySentence qs2 = new QuerySentence("What is Dick Clark's birthday","DATE");
            ArrayList<QuerySentence> doclist = new ArrayList<QuerySentence>();

                doclist.add(qs1);
                doclist.add(qs2);

                for(QuerySentence sent: docList)
                {
                   System.out.println("\nin loop : " + sent.label + sent.query);
                }

        }
```