# Add of an object via an input (arrayList)

Tags: java

Currently, I have 2 objects and I would like to enter a new object.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
players.add(new Player("Eric", 31, true));
players.add(new Player("Juliette", 28, false));
```

I am looking for a solution on StackOverFlow like below: But, I don't understand my error.

[How to add an object into ArrayList in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356889/how-to-add-an-object-into-arraylist-in-java)

Here is my method:

```
public static void addPlayer(List <Player> players){
    Scanner inputPlayer = new Scanner(System.in);
  
    System.out.print("Enter your player please : ");
    String name = inputPlayer.next();
    Player.add(name);

}
```

My error is -> ***Main.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
Player.add(name); text***

I don't understand my problem??

```
Player.add(name)
```

Here is my method called:

```
case 4 : System.out.println("Option 4 - : ");
         addPlayer(players);
break;
```

My Class `Player`

```
public class Player {

  public String name;
  public int age; 
  public boolean sex;

  public Player(String name, int age, boolean sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi @eric, you are calling Player.add instead of your parameter name: players.add

Comment: Hi @ gtgaxiola, I always have the same problem ```Main.java:75: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Player
    players.add(name); ``` ?

Comment: Think about what that statement means. You have a list of objects with the type `Player`. You're trying to add `name` which is a `String`, not a `Player`. So the error makes sense. Maybe you should have a look at a basic Java tutorial to get a feel for OOP?

Comment: You need age and sex inputs too `player.add(new Player(name, age, sex));`

Comment: You have to get from input all the required data for a new player, create a new player object and add that object to the list. Here you are just trying to add a String to to a List of Player

Comment: Thank you ! It's ok now with this ```players.add(new Player(name, age, sex)); ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take more inputs as your `Player` constructor requires `String name`, `int age` and `boolean sex`. Then you can instantiate a new Player object with `new Player(name, age, sex)` and add a Player object to your list with `players.add(new Player(name, age, sex));`.

```java
public static void addPlayer(List <Player> players){
    Scanner inputPlayer = new Scanner(System.in);
  
    System.out.print("Enter your player name please : ");
    String name = inputPlayer.next();
    System.out.print("Enter your player age please : ");
    int age = inputPlayer.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter your player sex (boolean) please : ");
    boolean sex = inputPlayer.nextBoolean();
    players.add(new Player(name, age, sex));

}
```

Comment: Thank you Mady, change just  `boolean sex = inputPlayer.nextBoolean();`